# Why did this question earn -50 reputation?

Tags: discussion

[Get Explorer preview to show .M3U file](https://superuser.com/questions/793464/get-explorer-preview-to-show-m3u-file)

[image]

Comment: The answer hides behind the triangle to the left of the question title.

Comment: You offered a bounty on Sep 9 '14

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You offered a bounty on it for 50 reputation on September 9th 2014. No answers so there was no chance of anyone getting a half bounty for 2 upvotes. Any bountied reputation is lost whether or not its awarded.

Comment: I added the date for you Journeyman :-)